# Why i have error when write buble sort in ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, quicksort

I have ArrayList with some words. 
I need to sort words by way of repetition. Thanks.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            words.addAll(Arrays.asList("returns", "such", "containing", "created", "maintain", "such", "discipline", "specified", "these", "such", "which", "such", "larger",
                    "deceptively", "difficult", "returns", "element", "care", "returns", "collection"));
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        String sortTemp;
        for (j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
            for (i = 0; i < words.size()-j; i++) {
                if (words.get(i).compareTo(words.get(i+1))>0) {
                    sortTemp = words.get(i);
                    words.set(i, words.get(i+1));
                    words.set(i+1, sortTemp);
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<words.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("Sorted Array", words.get(i));
        }
```

> 01-13 06:09:31.065 740-740/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                  Process: com.egoriku.task4_02, PID: 740
>                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.egoriku.task4_02/com.egoriku.task4_02.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 20, size is 20
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 20, size is 20
>                                                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                      at com.egoriku.task4_02.WorkWithArrayList.TaskThreeSortArrayList(MainActivity.java:51)
>                                                      at com.egoriku.task4_02.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post your error log.....

Comment: if (words.get(i).compareTo(words.get(i+1))>0) - this error

Comment: at first iteration when `j=0` this will be out of range `words.get(i+1)` when `i=19`, explain, from exception `Invalid index 20, size is 20 at `

Comment: Yazan, Thanks, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement bubble-sort. You can just use the `sort` method

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.addAll(Arrays.asList("returns", "such", "containing", "created", "maintain", "such", "discipline", "specified", "these", "such", "which", "such", "larger",
                "deceptively", "difficult", "returns", "element", "care", "returns", "collection"));
Collections.sort(words):
```

After this code fragment your ArrayList will be sorted

As for the error you are getting, you can clearly see that it is an IndexOutOfBounds Exception, which means the index of your arraylist elements is greater than it's size

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < words.size()-i-1; j++) { // you make the size smaller here
        if(words.get(j).compareTo(words.get(j+1)) > 0) {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have  write a sort itself.

Comment: ok, then you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, change the for and make it go until <words.size() -1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.addAll(Arrays.asList("returns", "such", "containing", "created", "maintain", "such", "discipline", "specified", "these", "such", "which", "such", "larger",
                "deceptively", "difficult", "returns", "element", "care", "returns", "collection"));
        String tempString;
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < words.size() - 1 -i; j++) {
                if(words.get(j).compareTo(words.get(j+1)) > 0) {
                    tempString = words.get(j);
                    words.set(j,words.get(j+1));
                    words.set(j+1,tempString);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0 ; index < words.size(); index ++){
            Log.d("MainActivity","element @ "+index+" : "+words.get(index));
        }
```